# Suggested edits alert is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This was always a minor annoyance, but now that we have people suggesting multiple edits every day, it's become a full-blown nuisance:

[image: Suggested edits]

(Note that even though it's next the word "mod", it does not refer to moderator flags; this is the icon for suggested edits).

All I see inside the red circle is a faint greenish blob.  Green text on red background is simply not readable; I don't even want to *think* about what colour-blindness would do to this.

Please fix this by changing at least one of the colours, preferably the background colour.

Answer (score 1):

This should be addressed now by the [Bigger, Blacker Bar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/).

Comment: I have a vague memory of major freak-outs concerning that bar. :) We're like cats, we don't *like* new stuff! Then the whole thing is gradually forgotten. Yawn - Feed me.